# place marker array google map with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

this is displaying marker on a map on giving lat and lng as 24.8 and 67.2

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

   position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.8, 67.2),
   map: map,
   title: 'Hello Karachi!'  }); 
 }
```

here is the function which alerts the lat and lng getting from database

```
function CallL()
{
  var len = document.getElementById('slcLon').length;
  for(var i=0; i<len ; i++)
  {
    alert(document.getElementById('slcLon').options[i].text);
  }
  var len2 = document.getElementById('slcLat').length;
  for(var j=0; j<len2 ; j++)
  {
    alert(document.getElementById('slcLat').options[j].text);
  }
}
```

Now what i want to do is to give lat and lng from this loop to POSITION in marker but when i try to pass loop there it gives me syntax error.

any help will be grateful displaying multiple markers on the map

Comment: What is the code that gives the syntax error?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: error comes when i place
  var len =   document.getElementById('slcLon').length; 
after  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

Comment: Do you want markers for every combination of latitude and longitude in the drop-downs? e.g. if the latitudes are 1, 2, 3 and longitudes are 7, 8, 9, 10 -- what markers would you want to appear?

Comment: Are you going to tell us the error? Or are you going to make folks guess?

Comment: i got lat and long in my seperate select boxes and i want to display markers on map using that lat and long present in my select box

Comment: @Stuart if the latitudes are 1 , 2, 3 and longitudes are 7 , 8, 9 i want to display markers on latlng (1,7) (2,8) (3,9)

Comment: @Stuart ? read my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear but you may want something like this:

```
var markers = [],
    latitudes = document.getElementById('slcLat'),
    longitudes = document.getElementById('slcLon');
for (var i = 0; i < latitudes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < longitudes.length; j++) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes.options[i].text, longitudes.options[j].text),
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello Karachi!'
        }));
    }
}
```

This would produce an array of markers for every combination of latitude and longitude that can be found in your `select`.

Edit: You indicate in the comments you don't want every combination, and that there are the same number of latitudes and longitudes which have to be paired together. So:

```
var markers = [],
    latitudes = document.getElementById('slcLat'),
    longitudes = document.getElementById('slcLon');
for (var i = 0; i < latitudes.length; i++) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes.options[i].text, longitudes.options[i].text),
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello Karachi!'
    }));
}
```

Comment: yes i have try this but now it is not showing any marker on the map